# pattern matching using "LIKE" in query ,postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

How to use "LIKE" to find rows that have for instance "R011","R012","R021","R022" in their string?I dont want "R01" nor "R02" to be selected.

```
SELECT 'Code'
FROM "public"."Test"
WHERE 'Code' LIKE 'R01%';
```

in a table named "Test" in column "Code" I have used Above query but the result was:

```
no rows found.
```

rows are like the following:

```
R(01-04,11)  Personnel professionnel des
R01  M้decins, dentistes et v้t้r.
R011 M้decins sp้cialistes
R022 Omnipraticiens et m้decins en m้decine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   public."Test"
WHERE  "Code" LIKE 'R0__';
```

This requires 2 characters after `'R0'`.

Your use of single quotes makes no sense. Start by reading about [identifiers and key words in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). My advice: do not use mixed case identifiers at all.
Then proceed to [information about pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html).

To be more specific you could use a regular expression like:

```
WHERE  "Code" ~ '^R0\d\d$';  -- allowing any 2 digits
```

or even:

```
WHERE  "Code" ~ '^R0[12]{2}$';  -- allowing only 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the underscore instead of the percent character. Underscore `_` matches a single character, where as percent `%` matches zero or more characters.

```
select 'R011' like 'R01_'
# true

select 'R01' like 'R01_'
# false
```

Or better yet you can use regular expressions to match just decimal characters.

```
select 'R011' ~ 'R\\d{3}'
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html